# Does f:attribute support other things than String?

Tags: list, jsf, tags, icefaces

I have the need to implement an `ice:commandButton` that passes a list to its backing bean. I'm not in a portlet scope, but in a tag scope.

I know that when I retrieve an `f:attribute` from the actionListener I get an object that has to be casted.

I want to know if I can map f:attribute to a `List<MyClass>`, where the actual instance of the list is *actually* an `ArrayList` and `MyClass` is serializable.

Something like:

MyTag.xhtml

```
<ice:commandButton actionListener="#{TagBean.doPrintItems}">
    <f:attribute name="collection" value="#{items}" />
</ice:commandButton>
//[other things]
```

MyPortlet.jspx

```
<my:printPopup items="#{BackingBean.itemsToPrint}" />
```

BackingBean.java

```
class BackingBean {
    private List<MyClass> itemsToPrint;

    //getter and setter of course
}
```

TagBean.java

```
class TagBean {
    private List<MyClass> collection;

    //getter and setter of course
    public void doPrint(ActionEvent e) {
        collection = (List<MyClass>) e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("collection");
    }
```

Do you think this is feasible? Thanks

Comment: It should just work. What is the problem you're facing? That's not clear from the question.

Comment: No problem yet. I have other tasks to perform before going into this. **If I get struck** with the button and find that this way is not viable, there is definitely a huge rollback for me to do. I expect to come into the button's thing next Monday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<f:attribute>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/attribute.html) gives you the possibility to add custom component attributes. They will be stored in the component tree state in the server side. So it can be any Java object type you want. The method [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) also hints that less or more; it  returns a `Map<String, Object>`, not a `Map<String, String>`. I believe your doubt is based on the fact that HTTP request parameters can only be strings. But component attributes should not be confused with HTTP request parameters.

Comment: Perfect clarification of the problem. So the attributes **are** stored server-side